# MySQLi Displaying Results in a Table

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to display generated data from PHPMyAdmin into a table using MySQLi and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Link</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                //Connection Information
            $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',''); //establish connection to db
            $selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'sample'); //select db
                
                //SQLi Statements
            $viewQuery = "select * from link JOIN categories";
            $execute = mysqli_query($connection,$viewQuery);
            if($execute)
                {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute))
                {
                    $link = $row['link'];
                    $category = $row['category'];
                }
                }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $link; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm new to MySQLi

Comment: At present you're reading the entire result set and overwriting two variables on each iteration. Only when you've finished do you emit the row with the last values you read. You need to move the code that emits each row inside the `while` loop that reads the result.

Comment: When I try to put the table row inside of the while loop, it keeps giving me an 'unexpected '<' error'

Comment: You can't just move the HTML as is. You need to add appropriate `?>` and `<?php` tags, or whatever method you elect to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the variables without using it. It should be like this i guess

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){
    $link = $row['link'];
    $category = $row['category'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $link; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```